# GRASS GIS G_malloc error

Tags: grass-gis

I am new to GIS.  I downloaded GRASS and the sample data sets and am attempting to use the tutorial at: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Quick_wxGUI_tutorial.  During the step, "Create a random surface", I get the error:

```
ERROR: G_malloc: unable to allocate 536870912 bytes of memory at spec_syn.c:50
```

My computer should be plenty powerful...
8GB RAM, Windows 8, 64-Bit

Any ideas why I can't seem to get through even the most basic tutorial?